# Как создать список из вложенного списка и обычного? (При этом каждый символ обычного списка должен встать в конец вложенного)

Tags: python-3.x, list, матрицы

Мне нужно чтобы получилось что то такое:
На ввод отправляются 2 списка A=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] и B=[4,4,4]
На выходе получается список C который равен [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
Я создал функцию, которая должна это делать, но почему то она сохраняет всё в список MatrixА. Таким образом, на выходе получается 2 одинаковых списка MatrixА и MatrixС и нормальный MatrixВ. Я просто не могу понять почему MatrixA как то меняется, если я работаю с её копией и совершенно её не трогаю. Заранее спасибо за помощь и извините за потраченное время, но я уже не знаю что делать

```
    def merging_matrices(MatrixA,MatrixB):
       MatrixC=MatrixA.copy()
       for i in range(len(MatrixC)):
           MatrixC[i].append(MatrixB[i])
       return (MatrixC)
   MatrixA=[[1,3,4],[0,3,9],[0,0,0]]
   MatrixB=[3,2,1]
   MatrixC=merging_matrices(MatrixA,MatrixB)
   print(MatrixA)
   print(MatrixB)
   print(MatrixC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Пример:***

```
li_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
li_2 = [4, 4, 4]

result = []
for li, x in zip(li_1, li_2):
    result.append(li + [x])

print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

У Вас ошибка возникает, потому что `copy` - это поверхностная копия, то есть ссылки на списки.

---

*Или так:*

```py
for i in range(len(li_1)):
    result.append(li_1[i] + [li_2[i]])
```

*Аналогично с помощью списковых включений:*

```py
result = [li + [x] for li, x in zip(li_1, li_2)]
```

```py
result = [li_1[i] + [li_2[i]] for i in range(len(li_1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать глубокую копию списка, используйте `deepcopy` в модуле `copy`:

```
import copy

def merging_matrices(MatrixA, MatrixB):
   MatrixC = copy.deepcopy(MatrixA)   # MatrixA.copy()
   for i in range(len(MatrixC)):
       MatrixC[i].append(MatrixB[i])
   return MatrixC

MatrixA = [[1,3,4],[0,3,9],[0,0,0]]
MatrixB = [3,2,1]

MatrixC=merging_matrices(MatrixA,MatrixB)

print(MatrixA)
[[1, 3, 4], [0, 3, 9], [0, 0, 0]]

print(MatrixB)
[3, 2, 1]

print(MatrixC)
[[1, 3, 4, 3], [0, 3, 9, 2], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```